# Multiple google analytics instances on a page?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, cookie

My company creates (and hosts) sites for many different clients. We allow clients to send us tracking code, including Google Analytics, and we put them on the page.

We would also like to include our own Google Analytics code for internal tracking.

When we first investigated this issue a couple years ago, Google warned about including multiple bits of GA tracking code on the same page due to cookie conflicts.

Has this changed? Is it now safe to include multiple copies with different accounts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answered very well on: [google analytics - multiple trackers on one page (cookie conflict)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239042/google-analytics-multiple-trackers-on-one-page-cookie-conflict)

Answer (score 0):

This is still not recommended to do, the consideration you mention above is still valid.

Source: http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsCookies.html (all the way at the bottom of the page).

Despite this recommendation, it did work for us for a landing page we did. Our affiliate wanted to include the landing page in his tracking, while our client wanted to track the visits as part of his own site-wide monitoring. We recommended against it, but implemented it with a "Don't call us if it breaks" on their insistence... never had that call.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two tracking codes you can just ask your client to grant access to you so you can view their analytics reports from your own Google account. Seen [this guide](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55500) on how to do that.